# Custom Policies API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I tried to create a custom policy, with a purpose a mask of service:

Original Services in API:

```
http://API/v1/profile
http://API/v1/account
```

With mask:

```
http://API/v1/user-profile
http://API/v1/user-account
```

And combination the answer of User Bee this a solution for this problem:

```
<switch source="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')">
    <case regex="/v1/kyc-profile">
        <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/v1/profile" scope="axis2"/>
    </case>
    <case regex="/v1/kyc-account">
        <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/v1/account" scope="axis2"/>
    </case>
</switch>
```

But this solution only works where the services is static, but I have others services, similar to:

```
http://API/v1/user-profile/{id-user}/details
http://API/v1/user-profile/{id-user}?expand=some_information
```

For the last service I have this:

```
<switch source="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')">
   <case regex="v1/user-profile/[\/\w\W]*">
        <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/v2/cliente/{id-user}?expand=some_information" scope="axis2"/>
   </case>
</switch>
```

**[/\w\W]*** This part is regular expression for **{id-user}?expand=some_information** and similar.

The problem is: I need put **dynamic value** because the property **value** (`<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"` **value="THIS"** `scope="axis2"/>`) takes this text, example:

Service before to policie

```
http://API/v1/user-profile/1?expand=some_information
```

Service after to policie

```
http://API/v1/user-profile/{id-user}?expand=some_information
```

My questions are:

1. How to put a dynamic value for the services similar to: `http://API/v1/user-profile/{id-user}?expand=some_information`?
2. For the other service, `http://API/v1/user-profile/{id-user}/details` I have the similar situacion, How a resolve?

Answer (score 1):

In your mediation sequence, try changing the backend URL as follows.

```
http://API/v1/user-profile/{uri.var.id-user}?expand=some_information
```

Example:

```
<switch source="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')">
   <case regex="v1/user-profile/[\/\w\W]*">
        <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/v2/cliente/{uri.var.id-user}?expand=some_information" scope="axis2"/>
   </case>
</switch>
```

Comment: I try this solution but not works, the service after to pass for the sequence have this, literally:
`https://API/v2/cliente/{uri.var.id-user}?expand=some_information`